# mongodb aggregation> $group max main array in document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the array of document need to group by date and give the max , min and avg of dat array by date. but unable to get the result , as dat is array.

```
    "ArryObj": [{
    "dat": [-84.2, -83.9, -84.9, -85.3, -86.8, -85.6, -84.6, -86.4],
    "Date": "26-05-2021",
    "Time": "13:02:42",
    },{
    "dat": [-90.2, -83.9, -84.9, -85.3, -86.0, -85.0, -84.2, -86.4],
    "Date": "26-05-2021",
    "Time": "13:02:42",
    },
    {
    "dat": [-100.2, -83.9, -90, -85.3, -86.0, -85.0, -84.2, -86.4],
    "Date": "27-05-2021",
    "Time": "13:02:42",
    },
    {
    "dat": [-80, -79.9, -63, -79.3, -78.0, -76.0, -77.2, -79.4],
    "Date": "28-05-2021",
    "Time": "13:02:42",
    }
]
```

**I tried :But we get the results**

```
db.deviceregisters.aggregate([
    {$match:{_id:ObjectId('00a71c5bcc4d86315b638250')}},
    {$project:{_id:0,
            dataCollection:1,
          
    }},
    {$unwind:"$ArryObj"},
    {
        $group:{_id:{date:"$ArryObj.Date"},maxNum:{$max:'$ArryObj.dat'},minNum: 
        {$min:'$ArryObj.dat'}}
    }
]).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$min`, `$max`, and `$avg` operator while grouping.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$ArryObj" },
  { "$unwind": "$ArryObj.dat" },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$ArryObj.Date",
      "average": { "$avg": "$ArryObj.dat" },
      "min": { $min: "$ArryObj.dat" },
      "max": { $max: "$ArryObj.dat" }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UFaXhjWRl6Y)**